# Navbar Toggle Functionality Does Not Function

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Problem: The issue is with Javascript code that is intended to toggle the visibility of a navbar component when a button is clicked.

The problem is that the elements (toggle button and navbar links) are not being selected or behaving as expected when the code is executed.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Troubleshooting steps taken:

1. Check and verify that elements exist in DOM
2. Wrapped JS code responsible for toggling the navbar menu on and off in a DOMContentLoaded Event.
3. Added console.log to determine if the elements are
   selected. The elements are properly selected.
4. Checked visibility toggle: The active class does not apply on clicked
5. Inspected the browser for any JS Errors
6. Browser compatibility: Tested in different browsers to further investigate issues
7. Tested the component functionality in isolation of the the other components and the toggle functionality works

Images of Source Code:[Navbar HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCgr3.png)
[Javascript code for navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwfGd.png)

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. We can't debug images of code

Comment: `toggleButton` is a list of buttons, you have to iterate over it.